# Highchart with webservice in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, json, web-services, highcharts, jsonp

What I would like to do is to get a simple string array (of numbers) into the Highchart from a webservice. For some reason, the chart is not even rendered and I cannot get any values through this.

In the Highchart's documentation I've found this example of sending data cross domains:

```
http://docs.highcharts.com/#cross-domain-data
```

This is their example (using php):

```
The serverside php file:
<?php
header("content-type: application/json"); 

$array = array(7,4,2,8,4,1,9,3,2,16,7,12);

echo $_GET['callback']. '('. json_encode($array) . ')';    

?>
```

The JavaScript calling the callback function using jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var options = {
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        type: 'spline'
    },
    series: [{}]
};

var url =  "http://url-to-your-remote-server/jsonp.php?callback=?";
$.getJSON(url,  function(data) {
options.series[0].data = data;
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
});
});
```

And now this is how my WebService.cs looks like:

```
public WebService () {
    //Uncomment the following line if using designed components 
    //InitializeComponent(); 
}

[WebMethod(Description = "ID:2")]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]

public string GetSomeValues() {

    string[] values = { "3", "5", "6", "7", "3"};

    string[][] jaggedTable = new string[values.Count()][];

    int i = 0;
    foreach (var value in values)
    {
        jaggedTable[i] = new string[] { value + "" };
        i++;
    }

    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    string strJSON = js.Serialize(jaggedTable);

    return strJSON;
}
```

And the Default.aspx:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var options = {
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'spline'
            },
            series: [{}]
        };

        var url = "WebService.asmx/GetSomeValues";
        $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
            options.series[0].data = data;
            var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
        });
    });
</script>
```

**UPDATE:** I've just seen that I'm getting in the console this error:

```
GET http://localhost:53566/WebService.asmx/GetSomeValues 500 (Internal Server Error)
jquery.min.js:130
c.extend.ajax jquery.min.js:130
c.extend.get jquery.min.js:122
c.extend.getJSON jquery.min.js:122
(anonymous function) highchart.aspx:23
c.extend.ready jquery.min.js:26
```

Where the anonymous function is:

```
$.getJSON(url, function (data) {
            options.series[0].data = data;
            var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
        });
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What you get in this line:  options.series[0].data = data; how you data / json looks like?

Comment: Actually it doesn't get me anything. I've just seen that in the console I get this error: GET http://localhost:53566/WebService.asmx/GetSomeValues 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: so the problem is with getting data, because it looks like no answer from webservice

Comment: I had to activate the HttpPost protocols in web.config. Now I receive answer from the webservice, but I think it's not translated into a json object... the output of the webservice is:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">[7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]</string>

Comment: Ok, I made some changes and now the output is:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"> [["3"],["5"],["6"],["7"],["3"]]</string>
Still the highchart doesn't show up...

Comment: If you receive still 500 error, it is related with server problem, not highcharts. 
Take look how to use XML: http://docs.highcharts.com/#preprocessing

Comment: I don't have the 500 error problem anymore.

Comment: I think the mistake it's on the asp.net side. I think actually I'm not sending a JSON object. Am I right? And for the parsing part, it should be JSON.parse(responseobj). Correct me if I'm wrong, please.

Comment: To be honest, I'm not asp.net developer, so I'm not sure if it is produced correct, in PHP you use json_encode($array).

Comment: Yes, I know how it should look like in PHP. Actually the problem it appears because ASP.NET still sends the data as XML, instead of JSON object (as it is told to).

Comment: So you need to familair with solution in asp.net which generate JSON